# jQuery: Event function not taking variable?

Tags: jquery, events

if a radio button is selected, i want a div to either show or hide. here is the code:

```
    // add event to hide unimportant details when var is disabled and show when enabled
    $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Enabled').change(function() {
        $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Unimportant').fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Disabled').change(function() {
        $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Unimportant').slideUp("slow");
    });
```

it should work (i alert tested that the event actually runs), but i think that for some reason, the variable `companyVarID` is unknown inside the event function. how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you didn't bother giving us any context, but chances are, you're changing the value of `companyVarID` after setting up these event handlers...

Somehow, you need to preserve that value (and not just the reference to the variable, which is adequately captured by the closure).

[Nick's solution will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3119352/jquery-event-function-not-taking-variable/3119374#3119374), *and* is fairly clean, but here's an alternate technique just to give you an idea of what's going on...

```
// ...something assigns a value to companyVarID

// put event-handler wireup in an anonymous function (to be called immediately)
// mask the outer variable with a parameter that can't be changed externally
(function(companyVarID) 
{
  // add event to hide unimportant details when var is disabled and show when enabled
  $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Enabled').change(function() {
    $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Unimportant').fadeIn("slow");
  });
  $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Disabled').change(function() {
    $('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Unimportant').slideUp("slow");
  });

 // pass the value of the outer variable to our anonymous function, allowing 
 // it to be captured in the event-handler closures
})(companyVarID);

// ...something changes the value of companyVarID
```

Comment: i like your way better to be honest =) a lot cleaner

Answer (score 1):

You can change it slightly, to be based of the current element's ID, like this:

```
$('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Enabled').change(function() {
    $('#' + this.id.replace('Enabled', 'Unimportant')).fadeIn("slow");
});
$('#companyVar' + companyVarID + 'Disabled').change(function() {
    $('#' + this.id.replace('Disabled', 'Unimportant')).slideUp("slow");
});
```